# how to get foreign key fields using reverse lookup in python/django ajax request (json)

Tags: ajax, django, python-2.7, django-queryset, django-ajax-selects

```
---models.py---

class Products(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=100)

class Image(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/home',blank=True,null=True)

---views.py----

if request.is_ajax():
    query = Products.objects.all()
    p = Paginator(query, 4)
    pagedata = p.page(1)
    jsondata = serializers.serialize('json', pagedata.object_list)
    data = json.dumps({'id' : jsondata,})
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

now in ajax data are in (pk, category, name, slug ,price)

but i also want foreign key field i.e  'image' using reverse lookup in ajax. i have already tried list but i want to do using reverse lookup..

Comment: i have tried list but this is not good method. so i am looking for reverse lookup. in my question i want to know  that  jsondata = serializers.serialize('json', pagedata.object_list.?????????) so what to write here so that i will get the fields of foreign table as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `serializers.serialize` and then `json.dumps` on your stuff. `serializers.serialize` is basically doing the same thing as `json.dumps`, to convert a python object into `json` string. What you need to do is manually construct a dictionary that contains all your data. You might need to loop through the `Product` list because there's no way to query for reverse relationships for each item in one run.